# 'from' parameter not supported c++ libcurl mailgun api Error 400

Tags: c++, email, libcurl, mailgun

I'm trying to send a email with the mailgun api using c++ libcurl. The api is returning the error `"message": "'from' parameter is not a valid address. please check documentation"`.

**code**

```
    CURL* curl;
    CURLcode res;
    std::string readBuffer;
    std::string user = "api:" + (std::string)"MY_API_KEY";
    std::string data = "from='Bob Marley <bob@host.com>'&to='MY_EMAIL@gmail.com'&subject='Hello'&text='hi'";

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/MY_SANDBOX_URL.mailgun.org/messages");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, user.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS, data.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writer);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

        std::cout << readBuffer << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
```

**Writer Function**

```
int writer(void* contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userp) {
    ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}
```

**output**

```
*   Trying 44.241.76.64:443...
* Connected to api.mailgun.net (44.241.76.64) port 443 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'api'
> POST /v3/sandbox7847fafcfb12470f8e94e86efad974b4.mailgun.org/messages HTTP/1.1
Host: api.mailgun.net
Authorization: Basic YXBpOmYyMmUxZWEyODgzMTc1YjliYTNmMWMzYTY1Y2JlMTM5LTQ4NzlmZjI3LWEyZjM5MDYw
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 89
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

* upload completely sent off: 89 out of 89 bytes
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 400 BAD REQUEST //Error 400 is thrown
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, x-requested-with, Authorization
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Max-Age: 600
< Cache-Control: no-store
< Content-Type: application/json
< Date: Tue, 15 Dec 2020 20:17:46 GMT
< Server: nginx
< Content-Length: 86
< Connection: keep-alive
<
* Connection #0 to host api.mailgun.net left intact
{
  "message": "'from' parameter is not a valid address. please check documentation"
}
```

Error 400 is thrown in the output.

**Documentation cURL example**

```
curl -s --user 'api:YOUR_API_KEY' \
    https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/messages \
    -F from='Excited User <mailgun@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>' \
    -F to=YOU@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME \
    -F to=bar@example.com \
    -F subject='Hello' \
    -F text='Testing some Mailgun awesomeness!'
```

Comment: Have you consulted the documentation?

Comment: @Chipster yes and I found nothing

Comment: have you tried using just an email in `from`?

Comment: also, why do you have double quotes around bob marley?

Comment: @RisingSun I have removed the quotes it didn't change anything. Also yes I have tried just an email in from it has the same output as well

Comment: How about a real email address in the from field?

Comment: @RisingSun Yes I have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not need to have quotes around the from-address and you must encode the lt/gt symbols:

```
"from='Bob Marley <bob@host.com>'&to='MY_EMAIL@gmail.com'&subject='Hello'&text='hi'";
```

you should use

```
"from=Bob Marley %3Cbob@host.com%3E&to='MY_EMAIL@gmail.com'&subject='Hello'&text='hi'";
```

Comment: I got it working with your percent encoding tip, however I think you had a typo. ```%3D``` should be ```%3E``` making the full string ```"from=Bob Marley %3Cbob@host.com%3E&to='MY_EMAIL@gmail.com'&subject='Hello'&text='hi'";```

Comment: you're right, this was a typo. thanks for clarifying, i edited my answer so it is correct now.